# completedAnimationSequenceNamed being called repeatedly

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I'm using cocos2d and cocosBuilder.
I'm trying to do a starting animation, and then once it has finished, make all of the children nodes perform their idle animations.

how I'm doing the starting animation:

(void) onEnter
{

```
[super onEnter];

CCLOG(@"onEnter being called");

// Schedule a selector that is called every frame
[self schedule:@selector(update:)];

// Make sure touches are enabled
self.touchEnabled = YES;

//intro animation
CCBAnimationManager* animationManager = self.userObject;
animationManager.delegate = self;

[animationManager runAnimationsForSequenceNamed:@"words"];
```

}

and this is what my completedAnimationSequenceNamed looks like:

(void) completedAnimationSequenceNamed:(NSString *)name{

```
CCLOG(@"animation ended");

for(CCNode *c in [self children])
{
    if([c isKindOfClass:[GameObject class]])
        [c playIdleAnimation];
}
```

}

For some reason, my completedAnimationSequenceNamed is being called repeatedly, many times a second, causing my children to constantly restart their idle animations.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I got it working, this is for anybody else running into this problem.

In order for the "(void) completedAnimationSequenceNamed:(NSString *)name" method to work properly you must have your animation start automatically (in the cocosBuilder project) instead of using running Animations from animationManager.

If I used the runAnimation method from animationManager, it (essentially) broke the callback method. But I just took that out and made the animation run automatically and it calledback as expected.